# Getting "poured out" in legal terminology

Tags: legalese, dialects

A common expression in Texas legal circles is,

> We got poured out down at the courthouse.

The clear meaning is that their team lost a lawsuit. I’ve been unable to find a source, first use, nor an origin from online sources.

Is the expression purely regional? Has it been used in other locales?

Comment: Sounds like dishwater or other liquid refuse.

Comment: I would take it to mean that you were all on a bus together, and that was the place where you all got out.

Comment: The suit didn't hold water, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The expression goes back to at least 1974 and does appear to have originated in Texas. At any rate, all three of the instances that I found from the period 1974–1989 are from Texas. Here are those three instances.

From *[Record of Proceedings, Texas Constitutional Convention: Official Proceedings, January 8, 1974–July 30, 1974*](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&id=W5sOAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22get+poured+out%22+jury&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22get+poured+out%22), volume 2 (1974):

> HOESTENBACH: Oh, yes, I have no intention of making it impossible to waive a jury, but I do want to insure that that's what you do.You can waive the jury. You don't have to come in, in a criminal case, and be in a situation where you could **get poured out of the boot** because you didn't comply with some technical language.

From *Minutes of the Advisory Committee for the Supreme Court of Texas* (November 12–13, 1982) [from a PDF file]:

> [Mr. W. James] KRONZER: Suppose you have it [a complaint] cast in an insufficiency mold, and you've got it written in the court of appeals in an insufficiency mold and you **get poured out** in that matter. And then you say, I am now going to go to the Supreme Court on a no evidence mold.

And from Michael Minns, [*The Underground Lawyer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=oRk7AQAAIAAJ&q=%22get+poured+out%22+judge&dq=%22get+poured+out%22+judge&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1-bvwzpX6AhWELzQIHcmzCIIQ6AF6BAgFEAI) (Katy, Texas: Gopher Publications, 1989):

> His voice started squeaking and quaking and he asked if I could give him a few minutes to get some help. I told him there was no way he was going to get any help. He was going to **get poured out** on the carpet. I was ready to fight.
>
> When the judge said, "Is the plaintiff ready?" Mr. I Know It All said "No." The judge asked "Why?" Mr. IKIA said, "I need a little help, your honor."  I approached the bench and said, "Your honor, we're ready for trial, I've brought six witnesses in here and have done two days of complete and full preparation. We need to go to trial now." The judge said, "Well, if he's not ready, I don't know if I can make him go to trial."

I never encountered the expression "get poured out" in three years of law school at the University of Texas in the late 1970s, but that may only show how out of the loop I was. I can say from my law school years that Texas lawyers are big on folksy, pseudo-cowboy expressions and imagery. I'm pretty sure that my first exposure to the expressions "all hat and no cattle" and "that dog won't hunt" came during those three years of study, although I had lived 16 of my first 18 years in Texas and never come across either phrase. Evidently Texas juries find such language charming and relatable (or pseudo-relatable).

In any event, the early instance of "get poured out of the boot" suggests that the original metaphor may have involved a cowboy pulling off his boot and pouring out its contents after stepping in water or muck of some kind to a depth that overflowed the top of his boot and flooded the interior. Clearly, being equated with the stuff that a cowboy might pour of his boot puts a person on the same level with some mighty unapppealing effluvia.

As for the exact legal sense of the term, I get the impression that it means not merely to lose in court but to lose in such a way that you are foreclosed from obtaining a full trial on the merits of your case. For example, from an [unidentified article](https://books.google.com/books?id=aztMAQAAIAAJ&q=%22got+poured+out%22+jury&dq=%22got+poured+out%22+jury&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR2N_V_5X6AhVUJH0KHYtkD1UQ6AF6BAgFEAI) in the [Dallas, Texas] *Southern Methodist University Law Review*, volume 52, issue 2 (1999):

> Also, I can see where at this point a client in Mrs. Peeler's shoes might be inclined to a rather dim view of getting any kind of justice from lawyers against lawyers. I mean, Peeler had pursued redress for her alleged injuries throough three different Texas courts. And she not only lost, she **got "poured out"** by a summary judgment that refused to allow her the right to present the claim to a jury of her peers. Do you suppose the courts, all three of them, may have been worried about allowing those peers to hear the case ? I mean would you want to let the "public" decide important things like public policy? Me neither.

And from Carlos Cisneros, [*The Land Grant*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aNLWtCyHL9sC&pg=PA47&dq=%22get+poured+out%22+court&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDsoGLgpb6AhXnlYkEHbSFC1YQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22get%20poured%20out%22%20court&f=false) (Houston, Texas: Arte Publico Press, 2012):

> “After you and the professor **get poured out** and get sent home packing with your tails between your legs, after the court entertains the foundation's motion for summary judgment..."
>
> Okay, that's not going to happen, but if it did," Alex interrupted her midsentence, "then what?"

Cisneros is identified in the front matter of the book as an attorney "who practices law in Brownsville [Texas]."

Answer (score 0):

“Poured out” can be used as a synonym for “rained out”.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20rained%20out

In sports, getting rained-out means that the game did not go to completion due to natural causes. Sometimes, the teams do not even begin to compete.

In the legal context, “poured out” suggests that the case was blocked from proceeding, but by more than a simple procedural delay (like the judge not showing up). An actual defeat would be referred to using a different sports metaphor, of which there are plenty.

The ever-helpful Wikipedia has a list of sports idioms:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sports_idioms

Comment: I suggest none of this works in British English… which says nothing about any other variant.

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be a religious reference, something about "poured-out wine and broken bread." I found a blog post [here](https://www.sethbarnes.com/?filename=stop-whining-being-poured-out-for-god-is-good) and then started looking at the expression in a biblical/Christian sense. Apparently, poured-out wine and broken bread expresses being tested by God to see if you are able to turn adversity into a blessing. [Here's another one](https://hehasyou.org/2019/09/01/broken-bread-and-poured-out-wine/).

This suggests to me that the losing attorneys are saying that they had a very bad day in court and that it's a test from God. The expression has most likely lost a lot of its biblical force and has become just a "bad day" expression.